# Rabin Encryption is not CCA secure

Tags: rabin-cryptosystem

Why is Rabin Encryption is considered as not CCA secure and how can I prove it? Any example would be helpful.

Comment: What research have you already done?  What is your definition of Rabin encryption?  What is the definition of CCA security?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- How would a CCA attack on textbook RSA work?
- Can you somehow modify a given ciphertext so that it is accepted by the decryption oracle while also yielding useful information afterwards?